# How to create a 2D array of repeated lower triangular arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a rectangular 2D array on which I want to apply a 2D indexing array (e.g. `arr[indexing_array]`).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1234)
arr = np.random.rand(4,9)

[[0.19 0.62 0.44 0.79 0.78 0.27 0.28 0.8  0.96]
 [0.88 0.36 0.5  0.68 0.71 0.37 0.56 0.5  0.01]
 [0.77 0.88 0.36 0.62 0.08 0.37 0.93 0.65 0.4 ]
 [0.79 0.32 0.57 0.87 0.44 0.8  0.14 0.7  0.7 ]]
```

I want the 2D indexing array to be a repeated lower triangular, something similar to this for the array `arr`:

```
[[False False False False False False False False False]
 [ True False False  True False False  True False False]
 [ True  True False  True  True False  True  True False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]]
```

Right now I'm creating this index with the following command:

```
nb_rep = 3 # The number of times the lower triangular array is repeated
k = 0 # An offset for the diagonal
np.arange(arr.shape[0])[:, None] + k > np.tile(np.arange(arr.shape[1]-6), nb_rep)
```

I tried a solution with `np.tril` and `np.tril_indices` functions, but it was quite slower than this solution. Is there a way to simplify this (I'm really not sure about my implementation on the right side of the >)? I used `np.tile`, but from what I found it might not be the fastest for replicating arrays.

Comment: If you look at the base `np.tri` function, you'll see all that family is based on an expression like `np.arange(5)[:,None]>np.arange(5)`.  So a custom version that creates the repeat directly should be just as good if not better.

Comment: I don't understand why the argument of the second call of the 'arange' function is 'arr.shape[1]-(arr.shape[1]-6)'
Your code does not produce the result you specified. Could it be that speed is not the only problem in your code?

Comment: @yannziselman, you are right, there was a typo, it should be `arr.shape[1]-6`. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if my method is the most efficient but it seems to run faster than your code.
Your code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1234)
arr = np.random.rand(4,9)

nb_rep = 3 # The number of times the lower triangular array is repeated
k = 0 # An offset for the diagonal
%timeit np.arange(arr.shape[0])[:, None] + k > np.tile(np.arange((arr.shape[1]-6)), nb_rep)
```

output:

```
The slowest run took 10.90 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 5: 12.9 µs per loop
```

My method:

```
%timeit np.arange(arr.shape[0])[:, None] + k > ((np.arange(6*nb_rep) % arr.shape[0])[None, :])
```

output:

```
The slowest run took 15.11 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 5: 6.02 µs per loop
```

using a much larger array the size of (4000, 9000), the difference is even more significant.
Output of testing your code:

```
100 loops, best of 5: 46.8 ms per loop
```

Output of testing my code:

```
100 loops, best of 5: 133 µs per loop
```

Comment: Very nice! Not using `np.tile` really helps!

Comment: Any reason you are doing the `[None, :]` on the right side of the >? It is a row vector while on the left side it is a column vector.

Comment: @m_power That's what i like to call "tensor outer operations" they follow the generalized logic of the matrix outer product. As far as i know, it's mostly used to compute covariance matrices but you can use if for a lot of other things. In this instace, it forms an array with the shape and content you need.